# Adiabatic invariants for rigid bodies

Tags: classical-mechanics, coordinate-systems, hamiltonian-formalism, rigid-body-dynamics, adiabatic

I Landau & Lifshitz I mechanics introduces adiabatic  through Hamiltonian that is dependent on some slowly changing parameter $\lambda$. After some derivation they got
$$I=\frac{1}{2\pi}\oint pdq=const.$$
This works for objects that have momentum and coordinate for example some point objects. But how to approach adiabatic invariants in case of rigid bodies?

Comment: That’s just the definition of the action variable...You should expand on how this relates to adiabatic invariants.

Comment: This action variable is constant of $\lambda$. Meaning it is adiabatic invariant. This is what Landau says.

Answer (score 1):

This invariant you are talking about is an integral of the tautological one-form of the symplectic phase space over a closed path in phase space. In the case of a rigid body, the invariant is the same. It is just that the configuration space of a rigid body is a Lie group, the phase space is the cotangent bundle of the Lie group and any cotangent bundle has a canonical (natural) tautological one form. In the case of a Lie group though, the cotangent bundle trivializes to a direct Cartesian product of the Lie group times its dual Lie algebra and the tautological form can also split int a Lie group component and dual algebra component.